# Laravel Send Email with HTML Elements

Tags: php, html, email, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to send email using SMTP in Laravel everything is good but the html elements is coming along in the email body.

i.e.,

**I am getting the below as mail**

```
<h2>Welcome</h2><br><p>Hello user</p><br><p>Thanks</p>
```

**Instead of**

### Welcome

Hello user

Thanks

Here is my Code :

What is the thing i am missing to make it applied on the content of the email

```
$msg = "<h2>Welcome</h2><br><p>Hello user</p><br><p>Thanks</p>"
$message->setBody($msg);                            
$message->to('user@gmail.com');                         
$message->subject('Welcome Mail');
```

Comment: try with `message->setBody($msg, 'text/html');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
    $msg = "Welcome 
    Hello user
    Thanks"
     $message->setBody($msg);                            
     $message->to('user@gmail.com');                         
     $message->subject('Welcome Mail');
```

Comment: I am currently using that, But i can't use any div or any html tags right ?.. Not even <a href> there :(

Comment: sure! if the format gives you problems just delete it! LOL

Comment: how you want your output.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to wrap your HTML code in body tag.
Take a look at [Laravel mail api](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail) too.

Comment: i saw the <body> tag there , but should i use it inside the mail function ?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but i guess the reason you are getting that msg with html tags in it, is that your code is not getting wrapped as HTML template. I would suggest to use standard laravel's way. Create a full html template with html,head and body tag and use Mail helper .$info = ['email'=>'user@gmail.com','name'=>'test user'];$data=['title'=>'test','info'=>'test'];
Mail::send('emails.test', $data, function($message) use ($info)
{
  $message->from('test@test.com, 'test');
  $message->to($user['email'], $user['name'])->subject('Welcome Mail');
});

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to send an email as HTML format:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You will have to use the `$headers` parameter.

> The last parameter, the headers, are optional for the function but required for sending HTML email, as this is where we are able to pass along the Content-Type declaration telling email clients to parse the email as HTML.

[Source](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

Or, if you just want to add breaking lines and you leave HTML elements:

```
$msg = "Welcome \n Hello user \n Thanks"
```